# Features of elliptic partial differential equations

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Short question with maybe long answer:

What are the features of the elliptic differential equations compared to hyperbolic and parabolic ones? And for example, why do physicists wish to get elliptic PDEs rather than hyperbolic ones?

Comment: You should add more details. But the question is good.

Comment: see here i hope this will help you http://www.math.tifr.res.in/~publ/ln/tifr10.pdf

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I need a summary. I found it already. But, thanks!